# How to delete one of each item in a python list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list that looks like this:

```
lst = ['p','p','p','p','p','m','m','m','n','n','n','n','d','d']
```

I want to remove one of each item. Currently my code looks like this:

```
for item in lst: 
    if (lst[-1] == lst[-2]) == True: 
        del(lst[-2])
```

That is if the last two items of the list are the same the second 
from the last should be deleted, but my code does not work.

Comment: What if you only have one of something?

Comment: Firstly: Never modify a list while looping over it !

Comment: Can you also have lists like this `lst = ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'd', 'd', 'p', 'p', 'n', 'm']`?

Comment: @Elmex80s - That would neither affect the performance nor the outcome if the code is written correctly.

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make the list unique. I assume you don't care about the order if you are doing that? So, use a set: `set(lst)`

Comment: Why do you want to "remove the second from the last item" from each group of common letters if they are all the same?  Also, what is the expected result?  What would you expect if letters were not grouped together, e.g. `["p", "p", "p", "n", "n", "p", "p"]` - what is the resut?

Comment: All the answer from JacobIRR, tlee and  Elmex80s solves my problem. I did not have a single occurrence of an item in my list. I mean each item occured at least twice. I recognize that i was looping over a changing list and that was another problem. i just wanted to remove one off each item. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `set` of the unique characters, loop over a **copy** of your list, and then remove items from the set while adding to an output list:

```
lst = ['p','p','p','p','p','m','m','m','n','n','n','n','d','d']

chars_to_remove = set(lst)
counter = len(chars_to_remove)
output = []

for item in lst[:]:
    if item in chars_to_remove:
        chars_to_remove.remove(item)
        continue
    else:
        output.append(item)

print(output)
```

Result:

`['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'd']`

**Note**: You still need to define what happens when there is only a single instance of a string in your list. (i.e. Does it get deleted as well?) In the above code, it will be deleted. But that can be changed like so, by adding another condition to the loop body:

Sample input : `lst = ['p','p','p','p','p','m','m','m','q','n','n','n','n','d','d']`

`for item in lst[:]:
    if lst[:].count(item) == 1:
        output.append(item)
        continue
    elif item in chars_to_remove:
        chars_to_remove.remove(item)
        continue
    else:
        output.append(item)`

Result: 
`['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'm', 'm', 'q', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'd']`

Comment: The code  i wrote added an extra item to all unique items. So i just waned to remove  just one of each unique item @JacobIRR. Your first code solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also, use `sum` and `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'd', 'd']
final = sum((list(g)[:-1] for _, g in groupby(lst)), [])
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a shot

```
result = []

for _, u in groupby(lst):
    new_u      = list(u)
    last_index = max(1, len(new_u) - 1)

    result += new_u[:last_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your expected result it.  Your code will not work because you are iterating a list while mutating it.  Instead, iterate over a copy (`lst[:]`).

```
for item in lst[:]: 
    if (lst[-1] == lst[-2]): 
        del(lst[-2])

lst
# ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'd']
```

However, you code still needs more to resolve:

> I want to remove one of each item

Try this instead:

```
import itertools as it


lst = ['p','p','p','p','p','m','m','m','n','n','n','n','d','d']
list(it.chain.from_iterable((list(g)[:-1] for _, g in it.groupby(lst))))
# ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'm', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'd']
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to remove single occurrences in the list, can be done in one line:

```
[lst.remove(c) for c in set(lst)]
```

This does not return the answer, but modifies your list in place, so `lst` is now trimmed.

Or wrapped into a potentially more useful function:

```
def remove_first_occurence(lst):
    l = lst.copy()
    [l.remove(c) for c in set(l)]
    return l
```

Comment: I do not recommend to use methods/functions which have side effects in a list comprehension like your `lst.remove(c)`.

Comment: All the answer from JacobIRR, tlee and  Elmex80s solves my problem. I did not have a single occurrence of an item in my list. I mean each item occured at least twice. I recognize that i was looping over a changing list and that was another problem. i just wanted to remove one off each item. Thank you very much guys.